# React app with api. Delete item for list doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

When I click on the Delete button, my code does not work. There could be a problem in the function `handleRemove`.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react' 
import axios from 'axios'


// API endPoint - Punk API
const API_URL = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers'

const List = () => {

    const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState([])
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL)
        setDrinks(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()    
    }, [])

    const handleRemove = (id) => {
        let groupd = drinks
        const newList = groupd.filter(group => group.id !== id)
        setDrinks(newList)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="search__main">
                    <input type='text' placeholder="search..." onChange={e => {setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className="search__box">
                        {drinks.filter((val) => {
                            if(searchTerm === ""){
                                return val
                            } else if(val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || val.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                                return val 
                            }
                        }).map((drink, key) => {
                            return(
                                <div key={key} className="search__mini__box">
                                    <div >
                                    <img src={drink.image_url} alt="drink" className="search__img"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4>{drink.name}</h4>
                                    <p>{drink.description}</p>
                                    <button type="button" onClick={handleRemove(drink.id)}>
                                        delete
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

Comment: Change `onClick={handleRemove(drink.id)}` to `onClick={()=>handleRemove(drink.id)}` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `handleRemove` function call is within a return statement, you need to call the function like so:

`onClick={() => handleRemove(drink.id)}`

What happens is, the function is called immediately on render if done the way you've proposed in your question. We want the function to be called only when the button is clicked.

Comment: thank you very munch.... you is very big .....congrats

Comment: @fjsfjsfjs Please accept my answer as the correct answer if it helped solve your problem. :)